# To Unit Test or not to Unit test this part

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a CSV class and a CSV parser class, and their unit tests. I want to find out if part of the unit test below must be removed:

```
public class CSV{

public string[] columns GetColumns()
        {                       
           var columns = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textReader.ReadLine()))
            {
               var columns = this.csvParser.GetColumns(line);              
            }

            return columns;
        }



  }

   [Test]
        public void GetColumns_ReturnsCorrectLine()
        {            
            reader.Setup(r => r.ReadLine()).Returns("a\tb\tc");


            //Act
            var columns = csvReader.GetColumns();

            //Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(columns!=null);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, columns.Length);

            Assert.AreEqual("a", columns[0]);
            Assert.AreEqual("b", columns[1]);
            Assert.AreEqual("c", columns[2]);
      }
```

Question

1) Must the three lines of code that assert columns (a,b,c) be removed?

2) Does the `GetColumns_ReturnsCorrectLine` test method perform correct unit test after removing the last three assertions

Please note that there are already code that unit tests the CSV parser's `GetColumns()` method. The functionality of GetColumns is to parse a tab-delimietered string and turn it into columns.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you are trying to test the CSV.GetColumns().

*GetColumns()* has three paths

1) textReader.ReadLine() returns null  => return null 
2) textReader.ReadLine() returns "" => return null 
3) testReader.ReadLine() returns !string.NullOrEmpty() => return the output from the CsvParser.

Three tests should be that

TextReader returns null => result is null 
TextReader returns "" => result is null 
TestReader returns  => result is return value of CsvParser.

The values returned by the CsvParser are not important - as you mention, that the CsvParser does its job properly is tested elsewhere - we just want to say that we return the output of the parser.

```
public interface ITextReader {
    string ReadLine();
}

public interface ICsvParser {
    string[] GetColumns(string line);
}

public class CSV {
    private readonly ITextReader textReader;
    private readonly ICsvParser csvParser;

    public CSV(ITextReader textReader, ICsvParser csvParser) {
         this.textReader = textReader;
         this.csvParser = csvParser;
    }

    public string[] GetColumns() {                       
        string[] columns = null;
        var line = this.textReader.ReadLine();          

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)){
           columns = this.csvParser.GetColumns(line);              
        }

        return columns;
    }

}

[TestClass]
public class CSVFixture {
    private Mock<ITextReader> mockTextReader;
    private Mock<ICsvParser> mockCsvParser;
    private CSV csv;

    private readonly static string [] Columns = new string[]{};

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup() {
        mockTextReader = new Mock<ITextReader>();
        mockCsvParser = new Mock<ICsvParser>();
        csv = new CSV(mockTextReader.Object, mockCsvParser.Object);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void NullLine() {
        Execute(null);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EmptyLine() {
        Execute("");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void PopulatedLine() {
        Execute("SomeLineValue", Columns);
    }

    private void Execute(string line, string[] expected = null) {
        mockTextReader.Setup(mk => mk.ReadLine()).Returns(line);
        mockCsvParser.Setup(mk => mk.GetColumns(line)).Returns(Columns);

        var actual = csv.GetColumns();

        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);

    }
}
```

**Other Points:** As long as the CsvParser is only invoked from here it is only moving code around but you might change the CsvParser so that if the input is null or empty it returns null. This means that you do not have to check for it every time you invoke the CsvParser.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. You said the GetColumns() has three paths. When ReadLIne returns NULL and string.empty, both are the same path, rather than two path. However, it might be considered two different scenarios. Good stuff. I want to know more on what to or not unit test. I wonder if you can remmomend reading materials. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @pingpong I'd recommend 'The Art of Unit Testing', by Roy Osherove and 'Working Effectively with Legacy Code' by Michael Feathers. Also, just reading through questions and answers here :)

Comment: Thanks. I read 'The Art of Unit Testing'. I know the basics. I want to know deeper. Isn't the 'Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests' by Steve Freeman better than WEWLC. Which one should I read first if both are good? In particular, I want to know what should or should not be unit tested, and more. In the meantime, I am writing related topics on the web. But I still prefer books.

Comment: @pingpong I haven't read GOOS so I can't compare it to WEWLC.  WEWLC gives good ideas on how to incrementally add testing to code that does not have unit tests and thus introduces a lot of useful techniques but does assume that you know what you want to test. I haven't seen many definitive lists on what to test, just lots of guidelines - possibly because any such list will just have to allow for too many exceptions and special cases.  Some code smells that I have found useful are 1) Am I using the same verification code in multiple tests, 2) am I reusing the same test data is multiple tests.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. If I cannot find it on the web, and books, I will post a question here.

Answer (score 2):

Those values should be checked but not like you are doing.

With NUnit, there is `CollectionAssert`:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new [] {"a", "b", "c"}, columns);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Must the three lines of code that assert columns (a,b,c) be removed?

tl;dr: **No**

If you want to make sure that "a\tb\tc" results in ["a", "b", "c"] and not ["b", "a", "c"], then you should leave them in. The first two lines only check if it's not null and the length, content could be anything.

> Please note that there are already code that unit tests the CSV
>   parser's GetColumns() method.

What are those tests? It's hard to tell if they overlap without seeing them.

Comment: The functionality of GetColumns is to parse a tab-delimietered string and turn it into columns. Because of it, I think those three lines should be removed.