# Unit Testing - Code examples to illustrate what should/should not be tested in class/method level.

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have been reading the related topics on the web including this site. But I cannot find one with lots of code to explain the subject in question.

I have been practicing TDD and unit testing for a while. I want to find out what should be and should not be unit tested in terms of class level, method level. For example, should I test everything (what is integration test for)? Within a target method, which lines of code should I unit-test? Are there any good principles, and practices on this area, or good reading materials with lots of code sample to illustrate.

The topic here is concerned with server side language, e.g. C#, Java.

**Update**

Please note that the books below don't cover what I am looking for (if i am correct)

[Pragmatic Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977616673)

[Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274)

Comment: You might get some examples on this related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101/what-are-some-good-unit-testing-examples

Comment: Why isn't your own experience teaching you something about what's useful to code and what's not?

Comment: @Lemoneadi the examples are good. But it might not cover general cases.

Comment: @duffymo I want to lean experiences of others. Maybe, they have deeper understandings, or different viewpoints.

Comment: Voted to close, sorry.  Not the place for this question.

Comment: @duffymo if you know the best palce, could you remmend it? But I think many developers have similar questions. Thus, I post here.

Comment: There is no "best place".  There isn't even one opinion that's true.   I see posts that argue back and forth about what's a "best practice" and what's not.  That's my point.

Comment: @duffymo I changed the title (removed practices). Maybe it is better now.

Comment: No, you need to read the FAQ.  This question isn't appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly speaking, unit testing should be white-box testing, in integration testing should be black-box.

That is to say, a unit test should rely on the inner workings of a unit of code, usually a method. As a developer you would inspect the possible paths of execution through the method and create a test case for each one. A unit test should also test the method in isolation. Any collaborators or input and output should be mocked, such that only the method under test is being executed by the unit test.

To find paths of execution you need to think about what possible inputs there will be to a method, and what branches (e.g. `if` statements and exceptions) there are. For instance

```
public boolean isYes() {
    return someValue.equals("yes");
}
```

This method has no `if` statements in it, but it has three paths of execution.

- If `someValue` is `"yes"` then the method returns `true`
- If `someValue` is some other string like `"Yes"`, `"no"`, `"bananas"`, or `""` it returns `false`
- If `someValue` is `null` it throws a `NullPointerException`

In this case, thinking about these paths of execution and writing unit tests to cover those cases helps you to think about what problems there might be with the method.

A test where the path of execution visits several units of code would be an integration test. You would run the test in terms of the overall inputs and outputs. You don't care *how* it works, just *that* it works.

Personally I would create unit tests based on my own knowledge of the code base, and for each method individually. I would create integration tests based on specifications and individual acceptance criteria from the requirements.

Comment: How to define execution paths? How many paths in CSV.GetColumns() method in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489683/to-unit-test-or-not-to-unit-test-this-part/15498252#15498252. I am looking for concrete examples (lots of them maybe) to solify my understanding.

Comment: Mainly look for `if` statements or exceptions. Also try to think about what possible values there are for each input. E.g. a `String` could be `null` or `""`. How will your method react to that input?

Comment: If I treat the same an input that could be null or "", should it be one execution path, or two execution path. I think I should be one. But I still need to create two unit tests for different scenaria. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I don't know about C#, but in Java null and "" are very different, and you should test for both.

Comment: I like the example you privded, which solifies my understanding more.

Answer (score 0):

[Pragmatic Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977616673) isn't the best in the Pragamatic series and the nunit techiques were pretty lightweight and dated when I read it years ago. BUT it's cheap enough and covers principles and practices.

[Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274) is also a worthwhile read.

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: I read both, but I don't find the answers. Maybe I missed them.